# PL/SQL find date in table

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm really stuck here.

e.g past_data table.

```
name|date      |hour   |data
____________________________________________________________
je  |06/05/2012|1       |32323
je  |06/05/2012|2       |43564
je  |20/05/2102|3       |12334
je  |06/05/2012|4       |123123
je  |13/05/2012|1       |133223
```

new_table

```
name|date      |hour   |data
____________________________________________________________
je  |06/05/2012|1       |32323
je  |06/05/2012|2       |43564
je  |20/05/2102|3       |12334
je  |06/05/2012|4       |123123
```

How do I write a program to find all day matches current day (today is Sunday) from column "date" table "past_date" copy to talbe "new_table". In the example you can see row with date = 06/05/2012 and 20/05/2012 from past_date table were copied into new_table because those two date are Sundays.

Then to loop this process 13 times (weeks in total) increasing 1 day each time e.g  sunday then monday then tuesday so on.

Please help.

Comment: Why 13 times ? there are only 7 days in the week... more than that, it will copy all records - because each record is as one of the days in the iteration ...

Comment: So how do I loop for 2 weeks ? I need 2 weeks from current run.

Comment: When you run the statements givven in the answers, you copy **all** the records from past_data which are of a specific day of the week (in my answer- today's day, in @Klas answer- sunday) if you iterate it on a whole week then you copy all the records from temp_data

Comment: Is it possible to do a simple loop some like a if loop ?

Declare 

my_date date;
i number;

my_date := SYSDATE;
i = 0;

if i != 13

then
INSERT INTO new_table (name, date, hour, data)
  SELECT name, date, hour, data
    FROM past_data
   WHERE to_char(my_date, 'd') = to_char(date, 'd')

my_date + 1;
i := i + 1;

End if
end;

Comment: Yes it is possible, I **reluctantly** updated my unswer.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you ask someone to clarify your requirements. What you say you want to do does not make sense, so you must have misunderstood something (or failed to communicate to us what you mean).

Comment: Yeap you are right, I've got it all wrong. I need only loop 7 times as there are only 7 days in a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PLSQL for this,
try this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (name, date, hour, data)
  SELECT name, date, hour, data
    FROM past_data
   WHERE to_char(sysdate, 'd') = to_char(date, 'd')
```

---

**UPDATE:** I really don't understand why and what is it good for, but since you asked...

If you use PLSQL then you can do:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0 .. 12 LOOP
    INSERT INTO new_table (name, date, hour, data)
      SELECT name, date, hour, data
        FROM past_data
       WHERE to_char(sysdate + i, 'd') = to_char(date, 'd');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: The brackets `(` .. `)`  are invalid around the SELECT part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I agree that they are **un-needed** but are you sure they're **invalid** ? (I don't mind removing them, I just find it more readable with them (it reminds me of the `values` clause))

Comment: Hmm. I could have sworn that they would throw an error, but apparently they do not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, this was a two part question but I was asked to cut down to simper terms. How do I loop this 13 more times and increase current day each time around ? please see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier to get a specific day of the week is 'D':

```
INSERT INTO new_table (name, date, hour, data)
  SELECT name, date, hour, data
    FROM past_data
   WHERE to_char(date, 'D') = 1
```

Comment: The brackets are invalid around the SELECT part

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, this was a two part question but I was asked to cut down to simper terms. How do I loop this 13 more times and increase current day each time around ? please see edited question.